# toggle on input checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I am trying to reproduce the behaviour of "Toggle All" functionality of http://jqueryui.com/download/

When I select on "Toggle All" checkbox I would like to check all the input box which are in the same div container. The contrary when I deselect the "Toggle All" checkbox.

For now I succeed to reproduce this behaviour partially.
Here is my http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2518/ , but I would like to implement something more smart.
Any hints?

```
$('.toggle input').click(function () {
    var weekdays;
    for (var i = 0 ; i < 7; i++) {
        weekdays = $('#contest_data_updatePeriodicity_days_' + i);
        weekdays.prop("checked", this.checked);
    }
});
```

P.S. 
I can use jquery or underscore

1) I would like to use `contest_data_updatePeriodicity_days_` selector
2) When I select all weekdays of a div container the "Toggle All" check box should be checked if it is not. The contrary when I deselect all fields.

[​http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2518/](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2518/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
weekdays.prop("checked", true);
```

Try this

```
weekdays.prop("checked", this.checked);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2518/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.closest` to get the parent div and then use the `this.checked` to toggle the status.

**Fixed DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2530/

```
$(this)
  .closest('.control-group')
  .find(':checkbox')
  .prop("checked", this.checked);
```

Also you missed the `<label class="toggle` for the `Toggle All Hours` control group. Fix the html like below,

```
<label class="toggle">
   <input type="checkbox" class="ui-widget-content"> Toggle All Hours
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or this, everyone has their own answer, but I think this is short and sweet:

EDIT: or event simple using a combination of Tats_innit's answer - http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2534/

```
$('.toggle input').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('div.control-group').find('input').attr("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please **demo** **Updated** http://jsfiddle.net/VqLfz/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/UPWt4/

Let JQ do all the effort for you: `this.checked` for bool check.

Hope it fits the casue `:)`

**code**

**New**

```
$('.toggle input').click(function () {

    var foo = this.checked;
    $(this).parent().parent().find(':input').each(function(){ 
        $(this).prop("checked", foo);
    });
});

​
```

**old**

```
$('.toggle input').click(function () {
    var weekdays;
    for (var i = 0 ; i < 7; i++) {
        weekdays = $('#contest_data_updatePeriodicity_days_' + i);
        weekdays.prop("checked", this.checked);
    }
});

​
```

Comment: +1 thanks for your suggestion. you reply partially to my question because I am asking also a way to avoid to write the id selector. I updated my question. thanks.

Comment: @LorraineBernard http://jsfiddle.net/VqLfz/ `:)` Updated my answer as well bruv! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Modified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2546/). : You are missed to add   before toggle hour checkbox.

```
$('.toggle input').click(function () {
 $(this).parents('div:first').find("input:checkbox").not(this).prop("checked",              $(this).prop("checked"));
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would not depend on the inclusion of your "Toggle All" checkbox in the same container as the ones to be toggled.  It's more flexible, and only slightly more work:

```
$.fn.toggleAll = function(selector) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $(selector).filter(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
    });
};
$('#all-days').toggleAll('[id^=contest_data_updatePeriodicity_days_]');
$('#all-hours').toggleAll('[id^=contest_data_updatePeriodicity_hours_]');
```

(This skips some error checking you probably should do.)  You can see this in action at http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/W7c9L/

Answer (score 0):

use the `.change` event on the weekday checkboxes to detect when all/none of them are checked and then set the checked state of the toggle checkbox

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2564/) ([fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2564/show))

```
var $checkBoxToggle = $('.toggle [type=checkbox]'),
    $checkBoxDays = $('#contest_data_updatePeriodicity_days [type=checkbox]'),
    checkBoxDaysCount = $checkBoxDays.length;

$checkBoxToggle.change(function() {
    $checkBoxDays.prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$checkBoxDays.change(function() {
    var daysChecked = $checkBoxDays.filter(':checked').length;
    switch(daysChecked)
    {
        case 0:
            $checkBoxToggle.prop('checked', false);
            break;
        case checkBoxDaysCount:
            $checkBoxToggle.prop('checked', true);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});​
```